# React - deal with multiple setState

Tags: reactjs

In my work, there is a FileUpload component that has an issue -
when I define it as multiple and add an onAdd function, then select multiple files simultaneously, it calls the onAdd function with every file separately, making it a problem when I want to setState the content.
(Assume that this component is a black box and can't be touched)

```
const [texts, setTexts] = useRecoilState(textAtom)
     

const onAdd(file: FileUploadItem) {
     ...
     reading file
     ...
     setTexts([fileText ,...texts]) // in case of multiple file AT THE SAME TIME - it won't save the first ones but only the last cuz the onAdds have been called before setState
}

return <FileUpload
         multiple
         onAdd={onAdd} />
```

I tried to do `texts.push` but it gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible`

What can I do?

Comment: @yousoumar thanks. theoretically, it should, but my VSC yells at me that setState cant accepts functions but only a value. `Argument of type '(prevTexts: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Texts[]'.ts(2345)`

Comment: const [texts, setTexts] = setState<string[]>([]) should be const [texts, setTexts] = useState<string[]>([])

Comment: @yousoumar yeah, it was a typo. in the IDE it's useState. but still - it's super weird that it doesn't work...:(

Comment: @yousoumar Just found out - I wanted to simplify the question and forgot to mention that I'm using useRecoilState and not useState.... should it work for useRecoilState as well? cuz it insists that I'll use a value and not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this form of `setTexts` to update the latest value of `texts`.

```
setTexts(texts => [fileText ,...texts])
```

Comment: I'm using hooks and it looks like it doesn't support callback in state... what is the useEffect equivalent for that?

Comment: Yes it does. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: Just found out - I wanted to simplify the question and forgot to mention that I'm using useRecoilState and not useState.... should it work for useRecoilState as well? cuz it insists that I'll use a value and not a function.

Comment: Yes. See: "The setter function may either take a new value as an argument or an updater function which receives the previous value as a parameter." https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/useRecoilState/

Comment: found the problem. I'm using typeScript and I extracted the useRecoilState to a outer function that its signature was [Texts[], (val: Texts[]) => void]. after changing it to [Texts[], SetterOrUpdater<Texts[]>] it worked. Thanks !